# Best way to keep Python script running?

Tags: python, cron, daemon, apscheduler

I'm using APScheduler to run some recurring tasks as follows:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from time import time, sleep

apsched = Scheduler()
apsched.start()

def doSomethingRecurring():
    pass  # Do something really interesting here..

apsched.add_interval_job(doSomethingRecurring, seconds=2)

while True:
    sleep(10)
```

Because the interval_job ends when this script ends I simply added the ending `while True` loop. I don't really know if this is the best, let alone pythonic way to do this though. Is there a "better" way of doing this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685695/how-do-i-run-long-term-infinite-python-processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the blocking scheduler. apsched.start() will just block. You have to set it up before starting.

EDIT: Some pseudocode in response to the comment.

```
apsched = BlockingScheduler()

def doSomethingRecurring():
    pass  # Do something really interesting here..

apsched.add_job(doSomethingRecurring, trigger='interval', seconds=2)

apsched.start() # will block
```

Comment: I'm kind of puzzled by your answer. As you can see I'm actually using `apsched.start()`. You're suggestng that I have to "set it up before starting". Could you explain what you mean? Some example code would be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. it runs a python script as a daemon :

```
import os
import time

from datetime import datetime
from daemon import runner


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path = '/var/run/mydaemon.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5

    def run(self):
        filepath = '/tmp/mydaemon/currenttime.txt'
        dirpath = os.path.dirname(filepath)
        while True:
            if not os.path.exists(dirpath) or not os.path.isdir(dirpath):
                os.makedirs(dirpath)
            f = open(filepath, 'w')
            f.write(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            f.close()
            time.sleep(10)


app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Usage:

```
> python mydaemon.py
usage: md.py start|stop|restart
> python mydaemon.py start
started with pid 8699
> python mydaemon.py stop
Terminating on signal 15
```